# Name of the song in Purgatory?

Tags: mass-effect-3, game-music-identification

I could stay for hours in the purgatory bar in the citadel just to listen to the music.

What's the name of that song, so I can put it on my iPod; on repeat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this the song you're referring to?

It's "Staggered Injection" by [Ekstrak](http://www.ekstrak.co.uk/).  It was also on the NFS: Carbon soundtrack, and you can find it on [iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/album/staggered/id315696998?i=315697095&ign-mpt=uo=5), [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bfd7kylfdiupjjio2et5f6ewxwe&rdid=song-Thqqifztjhaqfupypittbosvxc4&rdot=1), or [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002P4C6QU).  On that OST, it was just called "Staggered" - they sound the same to me, but you might preview the track to make sure it's the same (or at least close enough that you like it the same ;)

Comment: Note that this is also available on Spotify. The one which is on the Ekstrak album is slightly different than the one in ME3 though.